# ComboBox conected with data

Tags: database, combobox

I making a project in Visual Studio and I need to connect a Combobox to a database.

I have one set of data:

1. Audi - model 1
2. Audi - model 2
3. BMW - M1

If I select Audi in Combobox1 then in Combobox2 will only show model 1 and model 2.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using `c#` with that you can filter out results for second dropdown based on first dropdown like this:

```
private void Combobox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Combobox2.DataSource = null;
    if (Combobox1.SelectedValue.ToString() != "0")
    {
        string sql = string.Format("SELECT CarModel FROM Table WHERE Car = {0}", Combobox1.SelectedValue);
        Combobox2.DataSource = this.GetData(sql);
        Combobox2.DisplayMember = "CarModel";
        Combobox2.ValueMember = "ModelId"; //if there is an id for each model
        Combobox2.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Get Data Function:

```
private DataTable GetData(string sql)
{
    string constr = @"Data Source=.\SQL2014;Initial Catalog=Cascading_ddl;Integrated Security=true"; //modify as per your project
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row[0] = 0;
            row[1] = "Please select";
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

PS: I have mentioned Combobox1, Combobox2 just to give the context, you should consider proper naming convention.